# Cascading Dropdown List in Asp.net MVC4 using Json and Jquery not Populate

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Since two weeks, I'm trying to Create a ASP.NET MVC 4 Application which is contain 3 drop down lists. 
Those are Country, State and City .
I'm Following [this article](http://www.articlemirror.in/2014/01/populate-cascading-dropdown-list-in.html)

These database list details I call from databas

Connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CACD_Con" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Project_Name.csdl|res://*/Models.Project_Name.ssdl|res://*/Models.Project_Name.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.000;initial catalog=CACD;persist security info=True;user id=000;password=000000000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

controller class:

```
 public class CacadingController : Controller
{
    private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countrys, "CountryId", "CountryName");
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult StateList(int Id)
    {
        var state = from s in db.States
                       where s.CountryId == Id
                       select s;
        return Json(new SelectList(state.ToArray(), "StateId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult Citylist(int id)
    {
        var city = from c in db.Citys
                   where c.StateId == id
                   select c;
        return Json(new SelectList(city.ToArray(), "CityId", "CityName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public IList<State> Getstate(int CountryId)
    {
        return db.States.Where(m => m.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadClassesByCountryId(string CountryName)
    {
        var stateList = this.Getstate(Convert.ToInt32(CountryName));
        var stateData = stateList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.StateName,
            Value = m.CountryId.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(stateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Model Class :

```
public partial class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectContext()
            : base("CACD")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countrys { get; set; }
        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Citys { get; set; }

        }

    public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
    }


    public class State
    {
        [Key]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<City> Citys { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        [Key]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("State")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }

        public virtual State State { get; set; }
    }
```

View File(cshtml)

```
@model Project_Name.Models.ProjectContext

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.CountryId as SelectList, "Select a Country", new { id="Country" })<br />
    <select id="State" name="state"></select><br />
    <select id="city" name="City"></select><br />
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Country').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Cascading/StateList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a State</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                    items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#State').html(items);
            });
        });

        $('#State').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Cascading/Citylist/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a City</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                    items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#city').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But drop down's not showing any of data in database , Really appreciate if you can show me the correct path

Comment: Whats not working? Is the first dropdown (Countries) being populated?

Comment: not any of above dropdwon doesn't populate anything

Comment: Then you need to debug your code - does `db.Countrys` return any valid  data? (and you don't need `@model AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.ProjectContext` in the view - that not your model!)

Comment: its compile well without any error , but db.Countrys doesn't return  any data

Answer (score 1):

```
   where  cityList is list containing city model

var result = from item in cityList
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     value = item.CityId,
                                     text = item.Name
                                 };
                    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

and in script add
 $('#State').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Cascading/Citylist/' + $('#State').val(), function (data) {
                 var items = [];
                items.push("<option>Select City</option>");
                $.each(data, function () {
                    items.push("<option value=" + this.value + ">" + this.text + "</option>");
                });
                $(city).html(items.join(' '));
            });
        });

do same for state
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the first on my project but doesnt save the info on database .. to save Country I did on the view this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryId as SelectList, "Select a Country", new { id = "Country", @class = "form-control" })<br />
```

but the next doesnt save but if I change it like above the script doesn't work
Any help...

```
**<select id="StateId" name="state" class="form-control"></select><br />
<select id="CityId" name="City" class="form-control"></select><br />**
```

The  Script
    **

```
@section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/jscript">
        $(function () {
            $('#Country').change(function () {
                $.getJSON('/AddressBooks/StateList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data) {
                    var items = '<option>Select a State</option>';
                    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                        items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#StateId').html(items);
                    $('#CityId').html(null);
                });
            });

            $('#StateId').change(function () {
                $.getJSON('/AddressBooks/Citylist/' + $('#StateId').val(), function (data) {
                    var items = '<option>Select a City</option>';
                    $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                        items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#CityId').html(items);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

**

On the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "FullName");
            ViewBag.CountryId= new SelectList(db.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult StateList(int Id)
        {
            var state = from s in db.States
                        where s.CountryId == Id
                        select s;

            return Json(new SelectList(state.ToArray(), "StateId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult Citylist(int id)
        {
            var city = from c in db.Cities
                       where c.StateId == id
                       select c;

            return Json(new SelectList(city.ToArray(), "CityId", "CityName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public IList<State> Getstate(int CountryId)
        {
            return db.States.Where(m => m.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
        }
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult LoadClassesByCountryId(string CountryName)
        {
            var stateList = this.Getstate(Convert.ToInt32(CountryName));
            var stateData = stateList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.StateName,
                Value = m.CountryId.ToString(),
            });
            return Json(stateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
@Html.DropDownList("CountryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Country", @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<selectlistitem>(), "StateId", "StateName"), "Select State", new { id = "StateId", @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<selectlistitem>(), "CityId", "CityName"),"Select city",new { id = "CityId", @class = "form-control" })
```

Json

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
$(function () {
$('#Country').change(function () {
$('#StateId').html(null)
$('#CityId').html(null);
$.getJSON('/AddressBooks/StateList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data)        {
$.each(data, function (i, state) {
$("#StateId").append(
"<option value="" + state.Value + "">" + state.Text + "</option>")
});
});
});

$('#StateId').change(function () {
$('#CityId').html(null);
$.getJSON('/AddressBooks/Citylist/' + $('#StateId').val(), function (data) {
$.each(data, function (i, city) {
$("#CityId").append(
"<option value="" + city.Value + "">" + city.Text + "</option>");

});
});
});
});
</script>
}
```